# How to take off automatic scrollbar in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, scrollbar

in my web application there is a GridView control with 5 rows and paging which in some cases generates a vertical scroll bar automatically, how can i take it off? the scroll bar can move very little, something like a 1/10 of an inch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be achieved with CSS

setting

```
overflow:hidden;
```